# Docker folder size is greater than actual disk space

Tags: disk-space

The `du` command reports a total size of 276G for my `/var/lib/docker`. However, the `df` command says that the actual size of the device where `/` is mounted is just 219G.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2       219G  185G   24G  89% /
```

How is it possible to have a directory whose size is higher than the reported size of the device it is mounted on? I can understand this.

Comment: what's the result of `df /var/lib/docker`

Comment: `/dev/sdb2       219G  185G   24G  89% /`

Comment: OK, just making sure `/var/lib/docker` is not a different disk/partition :p

Comment: How do I check that?

The full `df` just says that `/dev/sdb2` is mounted on `/` and the other disk (`/dev/sda1`) is mounted on `/home`. Therefore I assume that `/var/lib/docker` must be mounted on `/dev/sdb2`.

Comment: Check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45773/101265

Comment: `How do I check that?` you just confirmed that it's not what I thought, so no need to "check"